# Error 403 on accessing http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup

Tags: macos, mysql

I am trying to set up phpmyadmin on BigSur 11.2.3. I have MySQL server running, put phpmyadmin folder to /usr/local, created config file and trying to access setup via http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup. Also tried with 127.0.0.1. But I get "Forbidden" error.

I haven't use XAMPP or other tools (I don't know if I need to, I am just starting as a junior :) ).

Maybe someone could help.

Comment: It would help to get more information on what software you have install (just MySQL or all of XAMPP) and how you installed it (are you following a website or book installation).

Comment: I installed MySQL server 8.0.23 and phpmyadmin phpMyAdmin-5.1-2.0-all-languages. No XAMPP.